# Why is $\frac{n!}{n^n} \leq \frac{2}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was reading the solution to an example problem for the  *Comparison Test for Series* regarding the following series:

$$\large \sum_{n = 1}\frac{n!}{n^n}$$

I understood every part of the answer except when he stated that

$$\large \frac{n!}{n^n} \leq \frac{2}{n^2}$$

The purpose of this was to find a $\large b_n$ such that $\large a_n \leq b_n $ for the Comparison Test, but I just couldn't grasp the way he justified it.

He explained it as follows:

If you write out the expression $\frac{n!}{n^n}$ in the general form you get:

$$\large \frac{n!}{n^n} = \frac{n}{n}\frac{(n-1)}{n}\frac{(n-2)}{n}....\frac{2}{n}\frac{1}{n}$$

Which makes perfect sennse. He then went on to explain how every term past $\large \frac{n}{n}$ would be less than $1$ which also makes sense, but *then* he said because of that we could state that
$$\frac{n!}{n^n} \leq \frac{2}{n}\frac{1}{n}$$ or $$\frac{n!}{n^n} \leq \frac{2}{n^2}$$ and could therefore use $\large b_n = \frac{2}{n^2}$ for the Comparison Test.

I just couldn't follow his logic when stating that $\large \frac{n!}{n^n} \leq \frac{2}{n^2}$. I believe it, but he said it in such a way as to imply that it was intuitive; that the conclusion could easily be stated given the presented information but it just didn't click for me. Could someone explain in greater detail why that relationship should be forthcoming?

Comment: If $a=bc$ and $0< b \leq 1$, then $a \leq c$. In your example, $b$ is the product of the terms up to $3/n$.

Comment: @user3776749 See my suggestion below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps look at it from a somewhat informal way, take $n=5$
We have to show $\frac{5!}{5^5}\leq \frac{2}{5^2}$ Now write out: $\frac{5.4.3.2.1}{5.5.5.5.5} \leq \frac{5.5.5.2.1}{5.5.5.5.5}$ That last fraction becomes $\frac{2}{5^2}$. Maybe you can see the general case for $n$ now

Comment: This really helped. Also @Aravind your more detailed explanation was very useful to once I'd wrapped my head around it more informally. Thanks all!

Comment: Whenever I have to deal with powers and factorials in a general case (meaning there is an $n$), I usually first take an arbitrary $n$ and see if I can get something out of that. Usually it becomes clear then and I can informally make a general case...